# Parallax with scaling works in Chrome but not in Firefox. Why?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<section id="parallax">
<div class="back" style="position:relative;background: 
url('pathandrealfilename.jpg') 
no-repeat; background-size:cover; 
background-position-x:50%;position:relative;"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section#parallax {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-style: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section#parallax .back {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    margin:-200px auto -250px;
    width: 1200px;   
    height:1200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-2px) scaleY(0.8); 
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scaleY(0.8); 
}
```

I don't get the desired parallex-effect in Firefox. Why? The transform is done the parallex effect is not achieved in Firefox (I want the scaling to be done when scrolling in combination with the transform). It works in Chrome.

**UPDATE**
Look at this site:
http://ajde2.wibergsweb.se/

In Chrome it scales when scrolling up and down

In Firefox it doesn't (the parallax effect is there, but it's not scaling)

Comment: I'd assume the problem comes from a lack of using `-moz-transform`, but can't be sure. Can you please update your question to use absolute URLs, thus providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem (the lack of moz-transform) but you could of course be right. The scale is done on the picture that is within the .back - div but it's not scaled accordingly to height when scrolling up and down with mouse. I want this effect: http://www.dior.com/home/en_int (look at the top picture)

Comment: My above code does the effect I want but it does not work in Firefox. It works in Chrome.

Comment: On the site you linked to, it appears to work in both Chrome and Firefox. What is the "*desired effect*" you are not getting? You have a trailing semicolon in the first `background-image:`, so that could be a problem with Chrome v.s. Firefox interpretation. However, you'll need to update your question in order for me to replicate the problem you're having. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Verifiable being the key word there.

Comment: Ok. I will update the question. The semicolon is just a typo. The site I linked to works as expected. My example works like that link with my code above - but in Chrome - not in Firefox.  The desired effect is that it scales up and down when scrolling up and down and the page.

Comment: @Obsidian Age: Unlikely. -moz-transform hasn't been needed for almost 5 years - -webkit-transform was still needed up until 3 years ago.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for the clarification. I'd assumed as much, though thought that maybe there was something else going on that that was reliant on the browser-specific syntax; nothing else immediately jumps out as the cause of the problem.